# Search in parent or any of childs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection of objects that have childs with unknown depth of nesting:

```
{ 
  name: "foo", 
  childs: [
    { name: "bar", childs[]},
    { 
      name: "SO", 
      childs[ 
        { name: "LINQ2Vodka"},
        { name: "KremlinWinterBearBalalaika"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to find any documents where any of child (or the main object itself) has "name" equal to some value? If not then what is the common way to do it?
Thank you!

UPDATE
As a workaround I can store parent and child objects flattenned (i.e. as array) along with the "chain" of ID's that holds their nested structure. Not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: I don't think MongoDB has the ability to do this kind of indefinite recursive search. Not sure if I understand your workaround the way it's worded, but I'm assuming it's a little like you'd do a many-to-many join in SQL? Each document has an array of document IDs which are its children.

Comment: @ClintPowell yes, but it's one to many (one parent for many children). The workaround is to bring properties out to a separate array (like [{ propId: 1, name: "foo"}, {propId: 2, name: "bar"}, { propId: 3, name: "SO"}...] and also keep the object hierarchy like { propId: 1, childs: [{propId: 2, childs:[{ propId: 3}, { propId: 4}]}]}. I can store chain and its props either within same collection or separately. So i'll be able easily to find document by any props, and the whole object with nested childs can be rendered in application layer.

Comment: It's not "impossible" but it is "in-advisable". Think XPath and XML DOM., where you can do this sort of thing because "everything is a node". BSON basically borrows from JSON so there is no inherrent "node" structure like this. You "could" write a recursive function in mapReduce ( or even just as JavaScript to query ) but that basically means inspecting **all** of **every** document. Not good. The optimal way is to "flatten" the structure. That way you are always "indexing" the same field. And that is optimal.